# How do you list the variables in the graph in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

This looks like it should work but it just prints an empty list after importing the pretrained Inception network: https://gist.github.com/tachim/6d44136171be86430dba16fecafa5872.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That shows contents of `VARIABLES` collection which does not get restored with `import_graph_def`. However, it does get restored when you [import meta graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html)

You could go over Graph and show all names for ops of type `Variable`

```
[op.name for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.op_def and op.op_def.name=='Variable']
```

This gives you name of the variable op in the Graph, rather than Python object wrapping it, so you'd be limited to low-level Graph-based API. IE, you can fetch the variable value by using this name as argument to `sess.run`, but there's no convenient way to get to its initializer or assign_op.

Comment: Just a side note, as for TF the keyword is "VariableV2". Looking for just "Variable" will return empty lists.

Comment: There's also ResourceVariable

Comment: Sorry, I meant as for TF1.4. Thank you very much for your constant and helpful insights. Do you know the difference between the three?

Comment: they are: almost deprecated, soon to be deprecated, and not yet planned to be deprecated, respectively

Comment: Is it normal that it get empty list for *.pb frozen model?  however `print(len([op.name for op in graph.get_operations()]))` is not empty